# Intellij IDEA не видит tools.jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я установил Itellij IDEA 15.0.2 на Windows 8.1, при первом запуске она попросила указать путь к JDK, я это сделал, после чего она успешно работала. Однако после перезагрузки компьютера она при запуске выдала ошибку `'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.`. Я проверил в командной строке JAVA_HOME, проверил наличие tools.jar в `JDK_directory/lib`, которая указана в переменной, все на месте, в чем может быть проблема?

---

При запуске с ярлыка idea.exe вылетает ошибка, если запустить idea64.exe - все работает.

Comment: Это полный текст ошибки, точно не пишет дальше: "Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE" ?

Comment: @will_hunting Попробуйте что-нибудь скомпилировать. При этом появиться окно с настройками конфигурации и там уже проверьте пути.

Comment: Да, пишет "Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE". Я не могу что-либо скомпилировать, поскольку эта ошибка про запуске студии, после чего она падает.

Comment: @will_hunting Ну, ясно же пишет. Укажите в JAVA_HOME путь не к JRE, а к JDK. Покажите содержимое JAVA_HOME